# I want to upload my app in app store. I didn't find the "requirements" field

Tags: iphone, app-store

I want to upload my app in app store. I didn't find the "requirements" field. I want use my app for 3gs and above.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add armv7 to the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in the app's plist.  That ARM architecture will limit the app's installation to 3GS and newer.

Comment: i want to support 3gs, 4g , ipad and ipod second generation and above. What should I do ?